# Align div top/bottom in a variable height td

Tags: html, css

I am using the HTML below:
I have a table with variable height. The height is set by the first TD content.
In the next TDs i want to have 2 divs. one align top and the other align bottom.

It doesnt seems to work since the 2nd and 3rd TDs have no explicit height.

I am looking for a pure HTML/CSS solution (without setting the height with JS)

Thanks for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div { 
        border: 1px solid red; 
    }
    td.container {
        position: relative;
    }
    td.container div.a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    td.container div.b {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><div>aasd asdas dasd<br />asd asdasdb<br />asd asdc<br /></div></td>
            <td class="container"><div class="a">a</div><div class="b">b</div></td>
            <td class="container"><div class="a">a</div><div class="b">b</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div>aasd asdas dasd<br />aasd asdas dasd<br />aasd asdas dasd<br />aasd asdas dasd<br />asd asdasdb<br />asd asdc<br /></div></td>
            <td class="container"><div class="a">a</div><div class="b">b</div></td>
            <td class="container"><div class="a">a</div><div class="b">b</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this ?
http://jsfiddle.net/ERPSA/
It's done using position:relative on the parent's td and position:absolute on the childs tds ...
this make the children using the td as reference for their position.

Comment: your link shows the problem exactly. the divs are hiding each other

Comment: You can add a size to the parent div if you know what it is ( look at http://jsfiddle.net/ERPSA/2/) In the case you don't know those div size, you can always use a rowspan with vertically aligned rows(valign) rows like this : http://jsfiddle.net/ERPSA/3/