# How to position a div on the bottom of a parent td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to place a `<div>` with fixed height (100px) and full width (100% of the parent `<td>`) within a `<td>` on the bottom. The `<td>` could be higher than the browsers viewport height as the content of the other `<td>`s are probably huge.

I already tried some solutions like [this (*link*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655767/align-div-top-bottom-in-a-variable-height-td), which is actually placing the div at the bottom of the browsers viewport.

**Edit:**
Here's a snippet of what is NOT working (according to the link above):

```
td {
    position: relative;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Is there any option to fix a `<div>` to the total bottom of a `<td>` using PHP, HTML, CSS or JavaScript (jQuery also)?

**Edit 3:**
Another problem occuring, when I use the solution as showed above is, that if I assign the div the property "position: absolute;" the "width: 100%;" relates to the viewport width, not the td width.

**Edit 4:**
The actual code of my page:

`html`:

```
<tr>
    <td id="content">
    </td>
    <td class="sidebar">
        <div class="internal">Notice</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

`css`:

```
#content{
    height: 1000px;
}
.sidebar{
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

div.internal{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

jsFiddle: [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/Z58ZW/)

Comment: If you change .sidebar position to absolute it does break things a lot because both right and left sidebars use that same class. I tried adding the absolute only in a style to the right side sidebar TD and it worked slightly better. But if you don't mind the question, why are you using tables to do the work of DIVs?

Comment: Because tables have a naturally structured behavior, in contrast to recursive and nested divs. Sure, I could replace every table, tr and td tag with a div tag and it would be the same layout, but being harder to read. I learned html 7 years ago, containing only tables cause div wasn't existing yet. Anyway it could also be, that my reset css file (to set every element to 0-style) broke the solution which is working in other web environments. After all somebody came up with a jQuery solution I'm using now. I wonder why I didn't thought of it by myself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... Legacy code I see... :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkyf4/1/)**

Use this to place the div at the bottom

```
td{
    position: absolute;
}

div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is an example with your code **[working link](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkyf4/3/)**

It work's for me in Chrome and IE. The Red section is your div. Is this the layout you want?

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to use a table layout you can try doing that: **[table layout](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkyf4/4/)**

**UPDATE 3: working only with tables**

If the previous solution didn't work for you I'm guessing your code isn't modular enough. If you want to use tables, you might want to use only tables. Add another table inside the requested cell like this: **[table inside the cell](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkyf4/6/)** . As much as I'm against it, I still think it's better than using JS to solve your problem. It will be easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: I already tried it. As I stated in my question this only positions the div on the bottom of the browsers viewport.

Comment: ok, i did not try to use absolute instead of relative in the td and it seems to work in the jsFiddle, even if the td is higher than the viewport

Comment: But it still does not work on my page because the "absolute" property moves my td to point 0;0

Comment: I added a link to my page

Comment: Still not working for 4 of 5 browsers, only opera can show it correct now

Comment: It is, but It was not working. Now I have a solution with jQuery

Comment: But you have to change the rowspan of the content td (and in my case the rowspan of all 9 tds which exist next to the problem td) which is also problematic, because I#m generating everything but the layout 100% dynamically via php. My php file is loading modules of which every module has other content, so when i have to rowspan I have to change the whole page layout

Answer (score 1):

You need using something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="sidebar">
            <div class="internal">Notice</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar{
width: 10%;
min-width: 200px;
height: 1000px;
background-color: green;
}
div.internal{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $div = $('div.internal');
var $td = $div.closest('td');

$div.width($td.width() + 2);
$div.css('top', ($td.height() - $div.height() + 12) + 'px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z58ZW/5/

Comment: When you look at your own fiddle, you can see, that the div is not positioned on the td bottom but on the viewport bottom

Comment: It works now with a combination of your jQuery Script and the css solution, thanks

Comment: Why JS? just use tables as you should. Look at my second solution.

Comment: @Paedow Using JS/JQuery to style a basic layout that you can achieve with only tables and basic CSS is the wrong way to go.

Comment: But I wasn't able to achieve it with css. The jQuery solution is the only solution working in my web environment, so it's obviously not only basic layout. Of course I could use another td within a new tr within a new table instead of a div, but that's not nice code.

Comment: @ItayGal: I watched your second solution, of which the screenshot is, but I don't see the same as you on my browser(s)

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
div.myClass{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

to the div.

**Example with the div positioned only on td bottom.**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chin/T3TqE/)

Comment: I already tried it. As I stated in my question this only positions the div on the bottom of the browsers viewport.

Comment: @Paedow try the Fiddle above where the div is positioned on the bottom of the TD

Comment: @Paedow The key here is having position: relative on TD and absolute on the div..anyway, which browser are you checking this on?

Comment: Firefox 26, Chrome 32, Opera 18, Safari 5 for Windows and Internet Explorer 9

Comment: I have the same problem on all five browsers